# string_agg substitute used in Derive transformation in Azure data flow expression language

Tags: azure-data-factory, expression, azure-synapse-pipeline

How do I convert this sql code "left(string_agg(zationClient, '; ') within group (order by zationClient)    , 100)" as a Transformation in data factory specifically in azure data flow expression language?

I am expecting an output like this with delimiter "NAFDQ-Trulife; EAQVN - Trulife"

I understand that string_agg is not supported in data flow expression language.

I tried substring(concat(zationClient, '; '), 1, 128) but it doesn't give the required result.

Comment: Can you give sample column values of zationClient column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to use a combination of derived column transformation, sort transformation and an aggregate transformation to get the desired result. The following is the starting data that I have:

[image]

- I have added a new column `tp` with a static value `1`.  This can be used to group the data as required.

[image]

- Now sort the data on the required column using sort transformation with configurations similar to the ones shown below;

[image]

- Now using the aggregate transformations, to group by the `tp` column. In the aggregates tab, use the required column with the following expression to get the desired results.

```
left(substring(toString(reduce(collect(con), '', #acc+';'+#item, #result)),2),100)
```

[image]

- The following is the entire Dataflow JSON:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sort1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "aggregate1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          id as short,",
                "          con as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(tp = 1) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sort(asc(con, true),",
                "     caseInsensitive: true) ~> sort1",
                "sort1 aggregate(groupBy(tp),",
                "     con = left(substring(toString(reduce(collect(con), '', #acc+';'+#item, #result)),2),100)) ~> aggregate1",
                "aggregate1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: false,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```